# When dividing binomial coefficients by $3$, why is remainder $1$ much more common than remainder $2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I was contemplating the nature of binomial coefficients, and came up with the following question.

Consider the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{r}$ where $1<r<n-1$, arranged in increasing order, with duplicates removed:

$6,10,15,20,21,28,35,36,45,55,56,\dots$ ([A006987](https://oeis.org/A006987))

Now consider the remainder when each term is divided by $3$.

$0,1,0,2,0,1,2,0,0,1,2,\dots$

Using Excel, I found that, for the first $10000$ terms:

- remainder $0$ occurs $6453$ times
- remainder $\color{red}{1}$ occurs $\color{red}{3276}$ times
- remainder $\color{red}{2}$ occurs $\color{red}{271}$ times

I understand why remainder $0$ occurs most frequently: for large $\binom{n}{r}=\dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, the numerator usually contains a higher power of $3$ than the denominator.

But why does remainder $1$ occur so much more frequently than remainder $2$?

Comment: See [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem). To get a $2$ you need $\binom{2}{1}$ to appear there, and an odd number of times. All of $\binom{1}{0},\binom{2}{0}, \binom{1}{1}$ give a $1$ factor, and those that give a zero, give you the lots of zeros.

Comment: It is interesting to make a Pascal's triangle $\bmod 3$.  There is an interesting pattern to the entries.

Comment: To get a start : $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ cannot be of the form $3k+2$ since then $n(n+1)$ would have to be of the form $3k+1$ which is impossible.